# How to deselect all rows programatically with reactdatagrid

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactdatagrid table in which users can select multiple rows via a checkbox column a per [the doc](https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/row-selection#multiple-selection-with-checkbox-column) example.

I would like to have a "clear all" button which deselects all rows programatically upon pressing. How can I programatically deselect all rows in reactdatagrid?

```
const [tableRef, setTableRef] = useState(null);

const onSelectionChange = useCallback(({ selected: selectedMap }) => {
        setSelected(selectedMap)
}, [])

<ReactDataGrid
    handle={tableRef}
    columns={cols}
    dataSource={data}
        checkboxColumn
    onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
/>
```

Comment: Please provide a link to codesandbox or analogues to facilitate answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @tpliakas - it really helped send me in the right direction! After a bit of searching, the function I'm after seems to now be called `deselectAll()` (instead of `clearSelected()` which no longer exists).

This is my final code that ended up working, in case someone else is searching:

```
const [tableRef, setTableRef] = useState(null);

const clearSelections = () => {
  tableRef.current.deselectAll();
}

<ReactDataGrid
    handle={setTableRef}
    onReady={setTableRef}
    columns={cols}
    dataSource={data}
    checkboxColumn
    onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
/>
```

I then use the `clearSelections` function upon clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it for some time now but the idea would be like this:

Add a ref to the [handle prop](https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/api-reference#props-handle) in ReactDataGrid, and then use the clearSelected from ref's current. Example:

```
const tableRef = useRef(null);

const clearSelections = () => {
  tableRef.current.clearSelected();
}

<ReactDataGrid
    handle={tableRef}
    columns={cols}
    dataSource={data}
    checkboxColumn
    onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
/>
```

I hope it helps.